# Decode special cyrillic characters

Tags: node.js, curl, browser, request

When running the following small snippet, we get weird characters in the terminal:

```
const http = require("http")
http.get("http://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2017/10/6/7157464/", res => {
    res.on("data", e => console.log(e.toString()))
})
```

...such as: `��������� ���`

Why is that happening?
When doing `curl http://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2017/10/6/7157464/`, we get raw question marks (such as: `<title>? ?  | ?? </title>`).

However, the browser seems to get good characters `<title>У Кахов...</title>`.

Is it the server which sends different content or the way how it's interpreted by the client (Node.js vs curl vs browsers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you request uses `Windows-1251` encoding, which is not supported by NodeJS out of the box:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

Browsers are smart enough to detect that and interpret correctly, apart from cURL and raw NodeJS requester. So, basically, you'll need a third-party module to convert the encoding, for example, [`iconv-lite`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite):

```
const http = require("http");
const iconv = require("iconv-lite");

http.get("http://www.pravda.com.ua/news/2017/10/6/7157464/", (res) => {
  res.pipe(iconv.decodeStream("win1251")).collect((err, body) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(body);
  })
});
```

In this snippet here I'm piping the response to the `iconv-lite` Transform stream, which does all the dirty work.